# OR retorna resultado não esperado

Tags: mysql, sql, operadores, operador-lógico

Estou a executar essa função

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `system_stats` WHERE  `name` = 1 OR 0 AND `us_id` = 0
```

Ela me retorna um valor igual a 1, porém este 1 não, quando eu executo separadamente dessa forma, ele me retorna 0, por que com o `OR` ele me retorna 1?

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `system_stats` WHERE  `name` = 1 AND `us_id` = 0
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `system_stats` WHERE  `name` = 0 AND `us_id` = 0
```

Comment: `name = 1 OR name = 0`

Comment: Problema persiste, `name` é INT com valores de 0 ou 1 @PapaCharlie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retorna assim porque você está mandando. O `OR` não pode ser usado de forma solta assim, não é texto em língua natural.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `system_stats` WHERE  `name` = 1 OR 0 AND `us_id` = 0
```

`name = 1` segundo você, dá falso.

`0` dá verdadeiro, já que isso é uma afirmação.

`us_id = 0`deve estar dando verdadeiro

`0 AND us_id = 0` dá verdadeiro. Esta sub-expressão é executada primeiro pela regra da precedência. È como se fosse uma multiplicação na aritmética.

Falso ou verdadeiro, dá verdadeiro, então retorna algo que você não quer.

Isso se chama [álgebra booleana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra). Se você não entender isto não vai conseguir programar.

Provavelmente o que você queria fazer é isto:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `system_stats` WHERE (`name` = 1 OR `name` = 0) AND `us_id` = 0
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Or.sql).

Entender a [precedência de operadores](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html) é muito importante. Tem que entender o que executa antes. Assim como saber que o produto tem precedência sobre a soma, tem que saber que o `AND` tem precedência sobre o `OR` e se quiser associar os dois termos do `OR` antes de pegar um deles e associar com o outro termo do `AND` tem que deixar isto explícito no código através dos parênteses.

Fora isto, se o problema é outro sua lógica está mais confusa ainda. Sua pergunta não deixa muito claro o que realmente você quer. É preciso aprender se expressar bem no programa e fora dele para conseguir os resultados esperados.

Comment: Entendi, mas mesmo assim ele me retorna o valor 1, estou perdido.

Comment: O que eu desejo é contar quantos rows existem com NAME = 1 ou 0 e com US_ID = 0, simples acho

Comment: Mas se o valor de `name` é sempre `0` ou `1` (conforme seu comentário lá em cima), por que você precisa dessa condição na pesquisa, @user3163662?

Comment: @bfavaretto sempre 0 ou 1 nos rows ja inseridos, mas futuramente irei por de 0-19

Comment: É o que eu falei para você, você tem que estudar programação de forma consistente. Não é tentando fazer as coisas na tentativa e erro que você vai entender todos os aspectos necessários. Eu poderia tentar ajudar mais se eu entendesse o que você realmente quer, quais são os dados que geram, essa situação, etc. Se você que tem tudo à sua disposição não consegue resolver, nós que não temos ficamos em situação mais desfavorável para conseguir ajudar.

Comment: Eu acho que o problema era simplesmente a precedência dos operadores, seus parênteses devem resolver.

Comment: Os parênteses resolveram, muito obrigado.